# Writer.book = ExcelWorkbook cant set attribute 'book'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

```
ExcelWorkbook = py.load_workbook(FilePath)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(FilePath, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = ExcelWorkbook
```

on one pc this runs perfectly fine on the other one
I get an error
AttributeError :can't set attribute 'book' on line 3
I'm lost on how to fix this as it works fine on one but not the other I also made sure to check that openpyxl was installed on the pc that it is not working on

is this the only way to combine 2 dataframes into a workbook that has separate sheets for each dataframe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your Pandas version on both computers.
I had the same issue and it seems like it is related to Pandas 1.5.0.
I removed it and used

```
pip install pandas==1.4.4
```

that fixed it for me

Comment: Great! two days searching and doing everything what is written. But that was only solution. thanx

Answer (score 0):

modify：`writer._book = ExcelWorkbook`   Before book add _ underline

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).